# How to join GitHub repositories in one big repository so that folders remain

Tags: github

Couple of months ago i started using github for the first time so i was very new and i couldn't figure out how to make one big repository with folders where every had one task collection that was given to us at Uni every week, so every time i made new repository

You can see the problem here [Github repositories](https://github.com/Wokstym?tab=repositories)

I would like to join it into one big repository called WDI, and if possible still have earlier commits

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new folder where you would collect all the repos that you like to keep together and create a new git repo using `git init` in your terminal. Seems simple enough and should be effective. Don't forget to push this "parent" repo to GitHub :)

Comment: Yeah, but is it possible to still have past commits?

Comment: Your past commits would be kept via the project level repos. Perhaps I am not understanding your goal. Are you trying to get rid of the smaller project repositories? If so than you would not be able to keep the git commit history.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/07/14/merge-git-repositories-and-preseve-commit-history/